# when change input type=radio to input type=image not work

Tags: html

good day, i'm trying to replace this code

```
<input type=radio name="y" value="1" onclick="this.form.submit()">work
<input type=radio name="n" value="1" onclick="this.form.submit()">broken
```

with this code

```
<input type=image name="y" value="1" onclick="this.form.submit()"><img src="/ar/serials/images/work.png">
<input type=image name="n" value="1" onclick="this.form.submit()"><img src="/ar/serials/images/broken.png">
```

but the submit doesn't work (no thing happen when click the images)

Comment: Why do you expect clicking an image to run the click event for an unrelated element?

Comment: sir, i need to replace the radio with the images, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i set this code and my problem has been resolved

```
  <input type=submit name="y" value="1" onclick="this.form.submit()" title='press here if the Serial works' style="background-color: black; border: 0px solid #900; background: url(/ar/serials/images/work.png) repeat-x; width:100px; height:40px; margin-left: 50px;">
  <input type=submit name="n" value="1" onclick="this.form.submit()" title='press here if the Serial not works' style="background-color: black; border: 0px solid #900; background: url(/ar/serials/images/broken.png) repeat-x; width:124px; height:40px;"><?php } else{echo "<font size='5' color='#33FFFF' face='arial'>"; echo "Thank you for Rating this Serial!";}?></td></form>
```

but one more question, can i put a code in style="" to change this background image onmouseover and onmouseout ?

Comment: please anyone reply, where is the people ? how can i put a code in style="" to change this background image onmouseover and onmouseout ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the src attribute directly into the input tag.

Example:

```
<input type=image name="y" value="1" onclick="this.form.submit()" src="/ar/serials/images/work.png"/>
```

Comment: i did but when i click it refresh the page only but when rewrite
input type=radio
it success with "Thank you for rating Serial"

Comment: please note: i but before this a captcha code and this image seems do same functions so, how can i make a Separates beween those captcha and rating codes ?

Comment: I didn't get you can you please clarify?

Comment: sir, i have captcha before this rating script, when i write the captcha in the required field and click the picture "work" instead submit captcha button it success as i clicked the captcha button, sorry for my english & hope you understand me